# Bootstrap navbar fechar

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown, nav-bar

Olá, estou usando o bootstrap versão 4.0 beta-2, e tenho uma dúvida, como faço para fechar o menu do navbar após clickar em um item da lista? Por padrão é necessário clickar no item e clickar novamente no menu para assim fechar.

Achei solução para isso na internet, mas era tudo utilizando versões antigas do Bootstrap,e aparentemente não funciona no meu o.o'.

código

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-default">
     <span class="navbar-brand" align = "center">
       <h2 class = "font-weight-light text-justify"><em>A s t r o </em> mania</h2>
     </span>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#Inicio">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
         </li>   
       </ul>
       <span class="navbar-text" align = "center">
           O melhor counteúdo de astronomia você encontra aqui no <em>A s t r o</em> mania.
       </span>
     </div> 
   </nav>
```

Comment: Observação: isso quando está em telas menores, quando ele se adapta a telas menores e aparece o "ícone" de menu do nav-bar...

Comment: Quando vc clica em um item no menu, não atualiza a página?

Comment: Não, não recarrega, ele apenas direciona para o target do link... e o target está na própria pagina, então ele só redireciona para o conteúdo e não fecha o menu sozinho...

Comment: Ta vendo o primeiro link da lista o "Inicio", a minha ideia era deixar fixo esse navbar, e quando o usuário estivesse navegando para baixo e quisesse voltar para cima, era só clickar no menu, e clickar no "Inicio". O problema é que depois de clikcar ele não fechar sozinho

Comment: Veja se a resposta ajudou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Bootstrap 4 (conforme especificado na pergunta, mas deve funcionar em versões anteriores recentes) o menu se fechará ao clicar em um item na lista do menu, com o seguinte escutador jQuery:

```
$(".nav-link").on("click", function(){
   $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```js
$(".nav-link").on("click", function(){
   $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
html, body, nav{ background: #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-default">
  <span class="navbar-brand" align = "center">
    <h2 class = "font-weight-light text-justify"><em>A s t r o </em> mania</h2>
  </span>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Inicio">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>   
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text" align = "center">
        O melhor counteúdo de astronomia você encontra aqui no <em>A s t r o</em> mania.
    </span>
  </div> 
</nav>
```